# Count values separately until certain amount of duplicates SQL

Tags: sql

I need a Statement that selects all patients and the amount of their appointments and when there are 3 or more appointments that are taking place on the same date they should be counted as one appointment

That is what my Statement looks so far

```
SELECT PATSuchname, Count(DISTINCT AKTDATUM) AS AKTAnz
FROM tblAktivitaeten
  LEFT OUTER JOIN tblPatienten ON (tblPatienten.PATID=tblAktivitaeten.PATID)
WHERE (AKTDeleted<>'J' OR AKTDeleted IS Null)
GROUP BY PATSuchname
ORDER BY AKTAnz DESC
```

The result should look like this

```
PATSuchname               Appointments           
----------------------------------------
Joey Patner                 13
Billy Jean                  15
Example Name                13
```

As you can see Joey Patner has 13 Appointments, in the real table though he has 15 appointments but three of them have the same Date and because of that they are only counted as 1

So how can i write a Statement that does exactly that?
(I am new to Stack Overflow, sorry if the format I use is wrong and tell me if it is.

In the table it looks like this.

```
tblPatienten
----------


PATSuchname      PATID                    
------------------------
Joey Patner       1      
Billy Jean        2       
Example Name      3
```

```
tblAktivitaeten
----------


AKTDatum        PATID      AKTID              
-----------------------------------------
08.02.2021       1          1000  ----
08.02.2021       1          1001  ---- So these 3 should counted as 1
08.02.2021       1          1002  ----
09.05.2021       1          1003
09.07.2021       2          1004  -- these 2 shouldn't be counted as 1
09.07.2021       2          1005  --
```

Comment: So two appointments on same day counts as 2?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, only 3 or more appointments should count as 1. Do you have any clue how this could work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two `GROUP BY` should do it:

```sql
SELECT
    x.PATID, PATSuchname, SUM(ApptCount)
FROM (
    SELECT
        PATID, AKTDatum, CASE WHEN COUNT(*) < 3 THEN COUNT(*) ELSE 1 END AS ApptCount
    FROM tblAktivitaeten
    GROUP BY
        PATID, AKTDatum
) AS x
LEFT JOIN tblPatienten ON tblPatienten.PATID = x.PATID
GROUP BY
    x.PATID, PATSuchname
```

Comment: Thanks bro! But how do i Join to the table "tblPatienten" now to Group them after PATSuchname? Or is that impossible

Comment: Different possible options, the simplest one is to JOIN the `x` with `tblPatienten` on `x.PATID = tblPatienten.PATID` but you then have to add patient name in group by.

Comment: I don't know why but the Join doesn't work for me Could you include it in your Answer please?

Comment: See revised answer.

Comment: Thanks man! Can I do something for you, like give you an Upvote or an Like on your Profile on this platform?

Comment: No, accept+upvote on this answer is enough